# How loading mechanism work?

Tags: c++

I've a number of files (pictures + fonts) that my c++ program (a game using Allegro library) need to load when it starts. It take me few seconds(about 2 seconds) to load before my program actually get into a running state. Files are being loaded like this:

```
gamePic[0] = al_load_bitmap("Data/pic01.jpg");
gamePic[1] = al_load_bitmap("Data/pic02.jpg");
gamePic[2] = al_load_bitmap("Data/pic03.jpg");
gamePic[3] = al_load_bitmap("Data/pic04.jpg");
gamePic[4] = al_load_bitmap("Data/pic05.jpg");
gamePic[5] = al_load_bitmap("Data/pic06.jpg");
gamePic[6] = al_load_bitmap("Data/pic07.jpg");
gamePic[7] = al_load_bitmap("Data/pic08.jpg");
gamePic[8] = al_load_bitmap("Data/pic09.jpg");
gamePic[9] = al_load_bitmap("Data/pic10.jpg");
gamePic[10] = al_load_bitmap("Data/pic11.jpg");
```

What mechanism should I apply so that I can run another animation that will show that "Files are being loaded..."?

Comment: Another thread with a GUI, which GUI toolkit are you using?

Comment: I'm using Allegro5 library.

Comment: Also, consider using a loop…

Answer (score 2):

1) Figure out which UI framework suits your app/environment best, some examples include Qt, MFC or (might suffice for a simple window and progress bar control) plain win32 native APIs (assuming a Windows environment, GTK+ would be somewhat equivalent to the aforementioned libraries on a linux system). AFAIK allegro does not provide UI APIs but it's a graphics / image manipulation library. You could of course render your own controls with allegro but that would be even harder

2) Create a UI window with the progress bar control and put it into a separate thread (still, on a Windows platform this is accomplished by having the window creation and message dispatching on a separate thread)

3) Synchronize your progress bar with your work and make sure the window is unloaded when the loading is complete (i.e. the thread is rejoined and terminated)

Answer (score 1):

As @Piotr S. already mentioned, you need threads. (You need to write your program in a parallel form.)

The threading model would look like this:

Shared memory: `percentCounter`

Thread 1: Loading the bitmaps and fonts, updating `percentCounter`

Thread 2: Displaying the loading bar

I'm not sure whether Allegro provides some thread functions. (As, e.g. SFML does)
Otherwise, if you use at least `C++11`, you use `std::thread` from the C++ standard library.

If you only want to show that the App is loading (and not "Not responding"), you could also write a simple "Loading" to the screen, just before or between loading the bitmaps.